# Change the label text after Response.End()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am exporting reports into an excel file on button click. When user click on a button I'm showing message "Report is generating..". After generating the report I want to hide the message. But as I'm using `Response.End()` the message is not hiding. Can anyone tell me how to call server side or java-script code after `Response.End()` or suggest me some other way?

Comment: I had once the same issue. Couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 4):

usually for this we open a second page, kind of popup which contains nothing but the data stream so the browser suggests to save or open the file.

this is done in another Response object so we can still control our main response object without the problem of having it closed or terminated.

Show some code and let's see how you are doing it right now.

Comment: i want to do it on same page, if u can suggest some solution that is on same page then pls.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: can u pls give me example how to use ajax for this issue, i have never used ajax. it will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Davide's solution; we solved this by opening a new page.

Assuming your have one page called Report.aspx, that also happens to have an 'export to excel' button.  If, for some reason, you are unable to extract that functionality into a static method, you can just do this:

On your page, when the user clicks on the export to excel button:

1. create an iframe with width/height: 1px/1px
2. set the url to the page, except pass in all the necessary parameters to generate the report
3. on the page.load or page.prerender of Report.aspx, have it use the parameters to execute the report and spit it out on the stream.

This way, your page will still be alive.

Answer (score 0):

You should use progress bar.
 http://www.webconcerns.co.uk/javascript/progressbar/progressbar.asp